# Type mismatch for 'mapObject' operator in Mule 3.8.0 DataWeave that worked in 3.9.0

Tags: mule, type-mismatch, dataweave

I built an API project that builds and sends a SOAP request to another service, based on parameters sent to the API. I inadvertently built the project in Mule 3.9.0 EE, when our production and dev Mule environments are 3.8.0 EE. The project works fine locally in 3.9.0, and it runs in 3.8.0 until it builds the request in Dataweave. It reports the following exception in 3.8.0:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.UnexpectedOperationTypesException: Type mismatch for 'mapObject' operator
     found :array, :function
  required :object, :function
```

I use two Dataweaves to build the request. The first builds the prompts used in the SOAP request from the parameters. The second builds the SOAP request and inserts the prompts.

The first Dataweave:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
[flowVars.parameterMap mapObject (value, key)->{
    PROMPT: {
        PSQueryName: "",
        UniquePromptName: key,
        FieldValue: value
    }
}]
```

The second Dataweave:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8"
%namespace SOAP-ENV  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
%namespace wsse  http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
%namespace qas  http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ_MSG.VERSION_1
%namespace qas1  http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ.VERSION_1
---
{
    SOAP-ENV#Envelope: {
        SOAP-ENV#Header: {
            wsse#Security @(SOAP-ENV#mustUnderstand: "1"): {
                wsse#UsernameToken: {
                    wsse#Username: "someUsername",
                    wsse#Password @(Type: "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"): "somePassword"
                }
            }
        },
        SOAP-ENV#Body: {
            qas#QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ_MSG: {
                qas1#QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ: {
                    QueryName: flowVars.queryName,
                    isConnectedQuery: "N",
                    OwnerType: flowVars.queryType,
                    BlockSizeKB: 0,
                    MaxRow: 0,
                    OutResultType: "webrowset",
                    OutResultFormat: "nonfile",
                    PROMPTS: payload.*PROMPT mapObject {
                        PROMPT: {
                            PSQueryName: $.PSQueryName when $.PSQueryName != "" otherwise {},
                            UniquePromptName: $.UniquePromptName,
                            FieldValue: $.FieldValue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In 3.9.0, the Dataweave transformed the SOAP request perfectly. In 3.8.0, it has issue with the `PROMPTS: payload.*PROMPT mapObject` statement in the second DataWeave.

What changed in 3.9.0 that made this work properly?

What work around can I do to resolve this issue in 3.8.0?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my own by combining the two Dataweaves, which separating the two proved to be unnecessary.

It does not answer what changes occurred in 3.9.0 that allowed it to work in the original project.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8"
%namespace SOAP-ENV  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
%namespace wsse  http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
%namespace qas  http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ_MSG.VERSION_1
%namespace qas1  http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ.VERSION_1
---
{
    SOAP-ENV#Envelope: {
        SOAP-ENV#Header: {
            wsse#Security @(SOAP-ENV#mustUnderstand: "1"): {
                wsse#UsernameToken: {
                    wsse#Username: "someUser",
                    wsse#Password @(Type: "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"): "somePassword"
                }
            }
        },
        SOAP-ENV#Body: {
            qas#QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ_MSG: {
                qas1#QAS_EXEQRY_SYNC_REQ: {
                    QueryName: flowVars.queryName,
                    isConnectedQuery: "N",
                    OwnerType: flowVars.queryType,
                    BlockSizeKB: 0,
                    MaxRow: 0,
                    OutResultType: "webrowset",
                    OutResultFormat: "nonfile",
                    PROMPTS: flowVars.parameterMap mapObject (value, key)->{
                        PROMPT: {
                            PSQueryName: "",
                            UniquePromptName: key,
                            FieldValue: value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is most probably a bug in 3.8.0 you can try by updating to the latest 3.8.6 version, or at least update only the DW plugin